# How to get values from programmatically created EditTexts?

Tags: android

I want to send some whole number from first activity to second one. That number is actually number of edittexts that i want to create.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_from_first_activity; i++) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        final LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.llid);
        ll.addView(editText);
}
```

After i filled up those fields with some data. How to get values from them when i click button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In your loop , you need not to call `ll = findViewById(R.id.layout_actual_effect);` .

2.Use `LinearLayout` as global variable , you can use it in other place

3.Use `ll.getChildAt(position)` to get View ,and use `editText.getText().toString()` to get value

4.Call `createEditText` before calling `getValue`

Try this .

```
private int num_from_first_activity = 3;
private LinearLayout ll;

/**
 * create EditText
 */
private void createEditText() {
    ll = findViewById(R.id.layout_actual_effect);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_from_first_activity; i++) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        ll.addView(editText);
    }
}

/**
 * get value from EditText
 *
 * @param position in LinearLayout
 * @return
 */
public String getValue(int position) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) ll.getChildAt(position);
    return editText.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop in the same `LinearLayout` you added but now you take Value:

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.llid);
for(int i=0; i<num_from_first_activity; i++) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) ll.getChildAt(i);

}
```

So you can see you loop so you can make a method for that to obtain the right item remember casting it to `EditText` if and only if you know they are `EditText` like this:

```
private String getTextAtEditTextIndex(int index){
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.llid);
    EditText editText = (EditText) ll.getChildAt(i);
    return editText.getText().toString();    
}
```

This method will be returning `String` from editText in the `EditText` at a particular index.